# GraphQL StrawberryCake Unable to resolve service for type <Interface>

Tags: asp.net-core, graphql, hotchocolate

I'm using StrawberryCake as GraphQL Client v12.6. I'm following their tutorial to getting started.

After use dotnet graphql init  -n ConferenceClient

Then register DI in Startup as follows

```
services.AddConferenceClient()
     .ConfigureHttpClient(client 
         => client.BaseAddress = new Uri("graphql_url_server_here"));;
```

I inject into controller as follows

```
private readonly IConferenceClient _conferenceClient;
    
SearchController(IConferenceClient conferenceClient) { _conferenceClient = conferenceClient; }
```

When I call to the endpoint of SearchController, it said

```
Unable to resolve service for type IConferenceClient
```

Does anyone get this error and how to solve it?